# Oracle select most commented news

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have two tables: `news` and `comments`.

`News` table:

```
CREATE TABLE "NEWS"
(
  "NEWS_ID"           NUMBER(20, 0),
  "SHORT_TEXT"        VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
  "FULL_TEXT"         VARCHAR2(2000 BYTE),
  "TITLE"             VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
  "CREATION_DATE"     TIMESTAMP(6),
  "MODIFICATION_DATE" DATE
)
```

`Comments` table:

```
CREATE TABLE "COMMENTS"
(
  "COMMENT_ID"    NUMBER(20, 0),
  "COMMENT_TEXT"  VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
  "CREATION_DATE" TIMESTAMP(6),
  "NEWS_ID"       NUMBER(20, 0)
)
```

Is there a way to select all news sorted by numbers of comments they have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could join the news table with an aggregate query of the number of comments:

```
SELECT    news.*, NVL(num_comments, 0) AS num_comments
FROM      news
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   news_id, COUNT(*) AS num_comments
           FROM     comments
           GROUP BY news_id) cmt on cmt.news_id = news.news_id
ORDER BY  num_comments DESC
```

Comment: There is an extra closing bracket at line 3.
But thanks for your fast reply.